# Following the Model and updating data in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I am working in cakephp and have a `Lessons` Belongsto `Kid` relationship, and `Kid hasMany Lessons` relationship.  This file is in the LessonsController.  I want to follow the Lesson and find the Kid that is associated with this lesson and change the `paid_lessons` variable associated with the `Kid`.  This line `$this->Lesson->Kid->set('paid_lessons','5');`
 is not working for some reason, although we have loaded the model.  Any suggestions?

```
public function lessoncompleted($id = null) {
    $this->loadModel('Kid');
    if (!$this->Lesson->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid task'));
    }
        $this->Lesson->id = $id;

        $this->Lesson->set('completed', 'yes');
        $this->Lesson->Kid->set('paid_lessons','5');

        if ($this->Lesson->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The task has been updated.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The task could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

since $this->Lesson->save($this->request->data) would call $this->set($data) during the save process, wont it override  $this->Lesson->set('completed', 'yes'); ?

Comment: no that does not seem to be occuring...we have no trouble setting that variable.  We just cannot figure out how to access the kid that is associated with the lesson and its variables...

Comment: you should use saveAssociated...since you are setting paid_lessons in the Kid models, but saving through the Lesson model, so if you want to get to the Kid model, you use $this->Lesson->save($this->request->data, array('deep'=>true))

Comment: hmm for whatever reason it still does not seem to be following the Lesson to get to the kid and update the data.  fyi I believe proper syntax is array('deep'=>'true'), but I do appreciate the help!

Comment: my bad, its saveAssociated not save... $this->Lesson->saveAssociated($this->request->data, array('deep'=>true));

Comment: didnt work either...im starting to think the issue might be with the $this->Lesson->Kid->set....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41288/discussion-between-ayo-akinyemi-and-john-smith)

Answer (score 0):

You are not using set [correctly](http://api.cakephp.org/2.0/class-Model.html#_set) In fact, you don't need it, since you are doing that in the controller and assuming you want to save data for models Lesson and Kid I would do this

```
//Assuming that Lesson hasMany Kid
public function lessoncompleted($id = null) {
    //$this->loadModel('Kid'); No need to load Kid because it is already loaded by Lesson
    if (!$this->Lesson->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid task'));
    }
    //$this->Lesson->id = $id; //not necessary because $this->request->data['Lesson']['id'] should contain the ID

    //$this->Lesson->set('completed', 'yes'); //no, see the next line
    $this->request->data['Lesson']['completed'] = 'yes';

    //$this->Lesson->Kid->set('paid_lessons','5'); //No, see next line
    $this->request->data['Lesson']['Kid'][0]['paid_lessons'] = 5;

    //if ($this->Lesson->save($this->request->data)) { //use saveAssociated
    if ($this->Lesson->saveAssociated($this->request->data)) { 
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The task has been updated.'));
        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The task could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
}
```

If this code doesn't work I would need to check the contents of $this->request->data, so paste it here if needed, also, I would be nice to read the associations that you have in Lesson and Kid models